# Is there such a thing as truly empirical evidence?

Tags: experimental-physics

As all evidence is reliant on human assumptions, is it accurate to refer to them as empirical? Is this just a quirk of terminology that we use due to the relatively consistent nature of the human perspective of physics?

I'm not sure if this belongs here or in philosophy, it's mostly a mix of the two I guess, but am looking for scientifically literate answers.

Is there anything which we can describe as being truly empirical evidence in physics?

Comment: In my opinion, this fully belongs into the realm of epistemology, i.e. philosophy of knowledge and science in general, not physics.

Comment: Yes, this is philosophy not physics. I will note that the consistency is not in the human perspective, but in that the universe keeps acting the same way when we do the same thing. Note also that following your train of thought to the extreme means nothing is empirical and everything is just a random guess based on how a given human looks at something at a given time. Not very satisfying, that.

Comment: In principle, ALL evidence that came from some type of measurement is empirical.  The hypothesis that is developed to explain that evidence will necessarily contain human assumptions.  In other words, the device that produced the measurements is an inanimate object, so it can't have "human assumptions".

Comment: Sure, but I'm after the perspective of physicists, so this seems like the right place to put it.

Comment: @JonCuster Isn't the universe acting in the same way, itself a human perspective? Could there be subtle differences which we aren't able to measure currently? Does empirical simply mean 'Empirical from a human perspective'? That would make sense, I think, although it also seems like empirical truths would then become outdated as time goes on, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: And none of that helps you at all in trying to do physics or any other science. As a human endeavor, science can suffer from human frailties. But that should not keep us from trying. What you want, however, is philosophy at best (and, frankly, not well thought out philosophy - I'd suggest Wittgenstein as a place to start if you want to dive in to it).

Comment: @JonCuster I agree, from a pragmatic point of view it's not the most useful of topics, but it's fascinating to ponder regardless. Thanks for the suggestion, I do intend to dive into this stuff quite firmly, as it's been on my mind for a while.

Comment: @DavidWhite But can the measuring device be trusted to be empirical? Is that not itself a human assumption?

Comment: Laws of Physics are irrefutable by definition, and must be based on empirical evidence, to become theory and must be be able to predict same events without error other than measurement limits, until proven otherwise. ( I think)

Comment: But if the laws of physics are irrefutable, how can they possibly be proven otherwise? Does that not mean they are either a) refutable or b) going against the scientific method? If the evidence is empirical, how can it be proven wrong at a later date?

Comment: This is a very legitimate question albeit one that fits better the fields of philosophy of science/epistemology and history of science. It has been the center of heated debate among philosophers and scientists for a very long time. I would suggest the book "Patterns of Discovery" by Norwood Russel Hanson as a good starting point for your research. Hanson holds the view that observation is indeed theory laden (as philosophers put it).

Comment: @CallumBradbury  I infer irrefutable to mean verifiable and without assumptions or beliefs and is repeatable,  follows the scientific method with evidence and deductive reasons. But I see some dispute this and have different definitions.

Comment: Yeah this is one of the issues I face when discussing this with anyone, the flexible nature of language makes it difficult to accurately comprehend what people are stating at any given time. One of the largest challenges, and potentially why the debate can be so heated as @retrospek mentioned.

Comment: Complex question, no definite answer. Try reading Kuhn to get some perspective: http://projektintegracija.pravo.hr/_download/repository/Kuhn_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions.pdf

Comment: @docscience thanks for the link, I'll add it to my list. I'm reading through Wittgenstein after Jon's recommendation, currently.

Comment: @CallumBradbury, you may have a different idea of "empirical" than I do.  I suggest that you think about this a bit, and attempt to concisely define what you think "empirical" means.

Comment: @DavidWhite To me, empirical evidence is basically anything that can be logically reasoned through objective observations.

Comment: How can a question asking for an example of empirical evidence be opinion based? Surely empirical evidence defies opinion entirely... I suspect some people don't want this conversation around for emotional reasons, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @callum bradbury: try reading the first chapter of Poppers *Logic of scientific discovery* to get some perspective on the history of science and epistemology.

Answer (score 2):

[Empirical](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/empirical) adjective

> 1. derived from or guided by experience or experiment.
> 2. depending upon experience or observation alone, without using scientific method or theory, especially as in medicine.
> 3. provable or verifiable by experience or experiment.

So by construction of the word experiments are empirical, measurements and observations.

Physicists should not navel gaze too much.

Comment: Doesn't everything rely on the scientific method? I have pondered this a lot, and even simple observational concepts such as sight seem to be ultimately dependent upon the scientific method. If sight is not empirical, is it possible for anything we observe to be so?

Comment: numbers , measurements,  organization of dimensions .... Sight is input but if there are no gauges /measurments it is just feelings and impressions

Comment: If dimensions are empirical, has the holographic universe theory been debunked? Numbers is an interesting one, but they seem more like philosophy than something which can be empirically proven to exist

Comment: There are dimensions in the holographic universe. Mathematics is magical. There is nothing philosophical about numbers, starting from counting apples and oranges.  If there are five apples there are five apples for everybody counting them.

Comment: @annav love your last comment. And ... just long enough to remove the lint!

Comment: @annav Aren't numbers just a byproduct of logic? I don't believe logic can be considered empirical under any definition. They're a concept generated by the mind, to help make sense of data retrieved, so how can they be absolute, if they're a structure generated by the mind?

Comment: This whole discussion is devolving into a huge exercise in semantics.  I vote to close the topic.

Comment: animals are not very philosophical http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20150826-the-animals-that-can-count

Comment: @DavidWhite just go away if it bothers you that much, no need to censor the discussion when it's getting interesting

Comment: @annav Regardless, philosophical principles can be applied to animals, so them being able to count does not make numbers objective from a physical observation standpoint.

Comment: the objective comes from it is being indisputable  that  "two and two makes four", in any culture or language or age (except infants)  or ... It is not like love or hate or anger,  nor a narrative. If a rock hits you a rock hits you. That is  objective and physics can calculate the probability of dying when hit by a rock, with numbers. not images, not words, not feelings

Comment: Yes, pragmatically it can, but objectively it cannot. It's not indisputable that 2 + 2 = 4, it depends upon the context it is being applied to.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be skating dangerously close to unreasonable skepticism.  Science has not been rigorously formalized, possibly because science must always be open to new theoretical and experimental methods and unexpected results.

"Science without epistemology is - insofar as it is thinkable at all - primitive and muddled.  However, no sooner has the epistemologist, who is seeking a clear system, fought his way through such a system, than he is inclined to interpret the thought-content of science in the sense of his system, and to reject whatever does not fit into his system.  The scientist, however, can not afford to carry his striving for epistemological systematic that far . . . He therefore must appear to the systematic epistemologist as an unscrupulous opportunist."    - **Albert Einstein** (*1949, p. 684*)

You may find some ideas to help clarify thoughts in this matter in Chapter 4 of *Fashionable Nonsense, Postmodern Intellectuals' Abuse of Science*, by Alan Sokal and Jean Bricmont.

Comment: As long as pragmatism is not abandoned, I don't believe solipsism is necessarily a bad thing. Many people reaching the obvious conclusion from my question may follow through with unreasonable conclusions, however I don't believe that discredits the question itself, or the answering of it in as close to an objective manner as possible.

Comment: @CallumBradbury : I do not mean to discredit your question.  The first sentence of my answer might be better worded.

Comment: Perhaps not, but I don't believe you intend to answer it either, so don't know what your goal is.

Comment: @CallumBradbury : My goal was to illustrate, with the quote from Einstein, the perspective of a physicist, which you asked for in a comment.  A rigorously reasoned answer, which your question deserves,  must be philosophical.  Chapter 4 of the book I cited is by two physicists, and shows a physicist's perspective of the philosophical issues.

Comment: Einstein's been dead for years though, I guess I'm after the perspective of a modern physicist that I can follow up on, and have a short back and forth with on the issue - Einstein doesn't qualify unfortunately. I don't believe the answer is necessarily philosophical, as empirical data surely does not rely on philosophy. One example would discredit the idea, and that should theoretically be possible in the realm of physics, if its possible anywhere